# Stop SKVideoNode Playing When Not In View Of Camera

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I use `SpriteKit` image recognition. `SpriteKit` works normally and I can image recognition. After recognition, I add a video on that picture. When the camera changes its direction and the videoNode is not in view, How can I remove the video?

simple code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Room", bundle: nil) else {
        fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
    }

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages

    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

}



func view(_ view: ARSKView, didAdd node: SKNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
        self.myImage == imageAnchor.referenceImage {
        node.addChild(self.addNode())
    }
}

private func addNode () -> SKVideoNode {
    let video = SKVideoNode(url: URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!)
    video.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    video.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    video.play()
    return video
}
```

Comment: You will need to post some code for us to help :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins added..

Comment: Do you mean you want the video to stop when it isn’t in view of the camera?

Comment: @JoshRobbins Yes

Answer (score 0):

Just do `camera.contains(videoNode)` If you want to check if the videoNode is in the camera or not.

basically on camera moved (Wherever you are moving the camera) do:

```
if !scene.camera.contains(videoNode){
    videoNode.pause()
}
```

Comment: I used this func, but it did not work.

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        if let scene = self.sceneView.scene, let camera = scene.camera {
            if let videoNode = self.videoPlay {
                if !camera.contains(videoNode) {
                    videoNode.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: camera returns nil

Comment: Seriously?  Need to do some of your own problem solving here.  If camera is nil, then how does this question even exist

Comment: nevermind, you are using ARKit,  You need to add an SKCameraNode to your game as well, since the ARCamera is something completely different.